# Responding to questions from emotionally distressed people

Tags: discussion, answers, moderation

Such questions have already been asked; also topics raised here might relate to such areas.

We have to be tactful in answering questions we might think are coming from a distressed person or might be of a topic relating to distress.

So they must be handled with care. Blunt but true answers might trigger undesired outcomes. So we have to have some discussion on best practices and the psychology  of how to answer these questions.

Comment: We have already discussed this sort of thing [here](http://meta.buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/197/what-to-do-about-suicide-ideation-posts). The idea is to flag them for admin to deal with. We're not a support group.

Comment: Thoughtful and compassionate answer. Be well.